# java apache.pdfbox SetTextHorizontalScaling

Tags: java, text, scale, pdfbox

I use the class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream for write text into PDF file.
I need to scale the text horizontally.

How can it be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide code to aid more people to help you.

Answer (score 0):

do this before drawing your text:

```
contentStream.transform(Matrix.getScaleInstance(2, 1));
```

this will enlarge on the x axis. If this effect is to be temporary, don't forget to put your draw commands within `saveGraphicsState()` and `restoreGraphicsState()`.

Alternatively, use `setTextMatrix()` with the same parameter. The later one has the advantage that one call replaces the previous.

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS CORRECT CODE:

```
        contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
        contentStream.beginText();
        contentStream.setFont(currentBaseFont, currentFontSize);

        //X HORIZONTAL SCALING
        Matrix scaleInstance = Matrix.getScaleInstance(scalaRiga / 100f, 1);
        contentStream.transform(scaleInstance);

        float rot = (float)((rotazione == 90)?(Math.PI / 2):(Math.PI * 2));
        contentStream.setTextMatrix(Matrix.getRotateInstance(rot, x, y));
        contentStream.showText(txpDati.getDati());            
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
```

THANK YOU TILMAN

FR